# MaxDOP = 8, does that mean 8 threads on all parallel operators?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I've been reading a bit on MaxDOP and have run into a question that I cant seem to find an answer for. If MaxDOP is set to a value, lets say 8, does that mean that SQL Server will always spin-up 8 threads on the parallel activities in the query, or could it decide to use less threads for a particular operator?

It boils down to: Is too many threads a performance concern if the workload is small (OLTP) and MaxDOP has been set too high?

A hint to the correct DMW would be nice. I got lost in DMW land, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: SQL Server will dynamically decide to use a parallel execution of the query, but will not exceed the maximum degree of parallelity (MAXDOP) that you have indicated.

The following article has some more detailed information: [How It Works: Maximizing Max Degree Of Parallelism (MAXDOP)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2013/09/27/how-it-works-maximizing-max-degree-of-parallelism-maxdop.aspx). I'll just cite a part of it here:

> There are several stages to determining the degree of parallelism (MAXDOP) a query can utilize.
>
> **Stage 1 – Compile**
>
> During complication SQL Server considers the hints, sp_configure and resource workgroup settings to see if a parallel plan should even be considered.  Only if the query operations allow parallel execution:
>
> ```
> If hint is present and > 1 then build a parallel plan
>
> else if no hint or hint (MAXDOP = 0)
>
>       if sp_configure setting is 1 but workload group > 1 then build a parallel plan
>
>       else if sp_configure setting is 0 or > 1 then build parallel plan
> ```
>
> **Stage 2 – Query Execution**
>
> When the query begins execution the runtime, degree of parallelism is determined.  This involves many factors, already outlined in SQL Server Books Online: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178065(v=SQL.105).aspx
>
> Before SQL Server looks at the idle workers and other factors it determines the target for the degree of parallelism.
>
> [... see details in article ...]
>
> If still 0 after the detailed calculations it is set to 64  (default max for SQL Server as documented in Books Online.) [...] SQL Server hard codes the 64 CPU target when the runtime target of MAXDOP is still 0 (default.)
>
> The MAXDOP target is now adjusted for:
>
> - Actual CPU count (affinity settings from sp_configure and the resource pool).
> - Certain query types (index build for example) look at the partitions
> - Other query type limitations that may exist
>
> Now SQL Server takes a look at the available workers (free workers for query execution.)   You can loosely calculate the free worker count on a scheduler using   *(Free workers = Current_workers_count – current_tasks_count)* from `sys.dm_os_schedulers`.
>
> Once the target is calculated the actual is determined by looking at the available resources to support a parallel execution.  This involves determining the node(s) and CPUs with available workers.
>
> [...]
>
> The worker location information is then used to target an appropriate set of CPUs to assign the parallel task to.
>
> Using XEvents you can monitor the MAXDOP decision logic.  For example:
>
> - XeSqlPkg::calculate_dop_begin
> - XeSqlPkg::calculate_dop
>
> You can monitor the number of parallel workers by querying: `sys.dm_os_tasks`

Answer (score 0):

It is only used to limit the max number of threads allowed per request:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094.aspx

So if SQL thinks using one thread is fastest it will just use one.

Generally on an OLTP system you will keep this on the low side. On large warehouse DB's you may want to keep a higher number.

unless you are seeing specific problems I wouldn't change it unless you are confident of the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can also decide to use less threads, you can see them from the actual plan with the number of rows handled by each thread. The maximum of threads is also for each of the parallel sections, and one query can have more than one section.

In addition to MAXDOP there is setting "cost threshold for parallelism" which decides if parallel plan is even considered for a query.